# React child receive old state props, NOT updated state props

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have a funky set up. I need a multi stage registration form. I have a parent:

```
class ContactPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stage:0,
        name:'',
        message:'',
        email:'',
        phone:''
    }
    this.setName=(e)=>{
        this.setState({name:e});
    }
    this.setMessage=(e)=>{
        this.setState({message:e});
    }
    this.setEmail=(e)=>{
        this.setState({email:e});
    }
    this.setPhone=(e)=>{
        this.setState({phone:e});
    }

    this.nextStage=()=>{
        if(this.state.stage < 3){
            this.setState({stage:this.state.stage+1})
        }
    }
    this.previousStage=()=>{
        if(this.state.stage >= 1){
            this.setState({stage:this.state.stage-1})
        }
    }
    this.stage = [
        <ContactName onChange={this.setName} />,
        <ContactInfo />,
        <ContactMessage name={this.state.name} onChange={this.setMessage} />,
        <Send />
    ]
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
           {this.stage[this.state.stage]}
           <button primary style={style.button} onClick={this.previousStage}> Previous </button>
                    <button primary style={style.button} onClick={this.nextStage}> Next </button>
                </div>
```

This component renders children based on in what stage of registration the user is. I can receive callbacks from children in parent(children do set the state of the parent), but, when passing state.name from parent to child as a prop, the child receives the initial state, which means the name is empty string.

Child component:

```
class ContactMessage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        message:'',
        name:''
    }
    this.handleChange=(event)=>{
        this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
        this.setState({message: event.target.value});
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    this.setState({name:props.name})
}


render(){

    return(
    <div>
                <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor='messageField'>
                    Message:
                    <input className='messageField' type="textfield" value={this.state.message}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
              </form>
            </div>
```

UPDATE: I am receiving initial props in the child components, not updated props from parent state. How do I receive new and updated props from parent state?

Comment: Just a guess but I think that, since you're setting the stage props in the constructor, the value is set to the empty string, rather than a reference to the given state object..

Comment: I was thinking the same way. But here is the deal. Im in first stage, i enter the name. The parent's state.name update, i go through to whatever stage, ant want to grab the state.name from the parent, via props, and I get empty string. How come I get the constructor state, although, the state was already updated?

Comment: Because you set up all stages in the constructor. You need to set the stage props on render. You basically prerender the component with a value of ""  and then add it afterwards.. I would probably write a method that returns the given stage from an index.

Comment: Can confirm, that when sending state as prop, I send out the old state. Lets say, if I pass state.stage to stage 3, the prop show stage:0. The question is. How do I send new and updated state, and not the initial value??

Comment: Wait a minute. I see you don’t bind “this” in your callbacks.. That means you’re probably setting the child components state instead! Try changing your callbacks to onChange={this.setMessage.bind(this)} so that when the child calls it “this” refers to the parent..

Comment: Binding is not the issue. Arrow functions do this for you, if I am not mistaking? Bloody state does not update. Could it be because I am rendering child components from a array?

Comment: No, arrow functions don’t do any binding. They don’t have their own scope if I understand correctly, but you still have to bind this when you pass it to another component..

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm having a similar problem, I've tried binding, and everything else you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, in ContactPage you trying to set event (e) as value of state.name instead of setting `this.setState({ name: e.target.value })` in `this. setName` method.
By the way, you don't have to pass everything through constructor.
For example,

```html
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ''
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am grabbing e.target.value in the child component, and passing the value to the parent's setName

Comment: Ah, sorry, when you trying to display `this.state.name`, which is empty, but when you pass 'string' as prop it passes *once* in 'componentWillMount' and sets in state. You can try to use componentWillRecieveProps to handle prop changes.

Comment: `componentWillMount` fires once when component actually mounts. So when you change state in parent component and pass as prop, but in children you try to display children's state value, which updates through props once at mounting.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps() is not firing, when passing state, or string. But if I pass string, I can see it in {this.props.name}

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the stage array into its own method. Something like:

```
class ContactPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      stage: 0,
      name: 0
      // and so on
    }
  }
  getStage(index) {
    let stages = [
      <ContactName onChange={this.setName} />,
      <ContactInfo />,
      <ContactMessage name={this.state.name} onChange={this.setMessage} />,
      <Send />
    ];
    return stages[index];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      {this.getStage(this.state.stage)}
      <AllTheOtherStuff />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks, like better looking code, but the damn name still do not render. I am ready to bang my head against the wall. I event tried creating getName() on a parent and passing it to child as a prop, and then executing it. Still getting empty line. By the way, I removed all the values from constructor. And also, I can confirm, that the state of name is changing. Something is not re-rendering as it should. Maybe the components in array are all preloaded, and do not update, no mater what I do. Tried forceUpdate() on everything.

Answer (score 0):

3 things I'm noticing here, which may or may not be your problem.

First: Using state the way you are is inherently bug prone. If you are displaying `this.state.name`, and are setting `name` from `this.props`, both in the `constructor` and `componentWillReceiveProps`, then just skip the middle man and display `this.props.name` instead. Trying to maintain a correct state when the value in state is coming from props is really easy to mess up, thus it is better to just use props directly.

Second: I believe your problem is a mixture of 1 and 2 here, but you are declaring your `stage` variable in your `constructor`, so it is only going to use what it has available in the `constructor`. Move `this.stage` into your `render()` and it should display the correct state information.

Third: the way you are using componentWillReceiveProps can lead to confusion. It is better to name your variables something that accurately describes what they are, without possible confusion. I would change `componentWillReceiveProps(props)` to `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` since `nextProps` is more explicit about what those props are you are dealing with.